# Is there a way I can sort this array

Tags: php

I want to sort a returned value from a while loop here is my code

```
public function Getter($stream){
    $sql1 = "SELECT reg_no FROM hs_registration ";
    $sql1.= "JOIN hs_students USING(reg_no) WHERE class_id = 2";
    $result1 = $database->query($sql1);
    $num1 = $database->num_rows($result1);
    if($num1 > 0){
       $records = array();
       $number_of_sub = getNoSub();
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
           //return individual score
           $total =  $this->totalScoreSpreadSheet($row['reg_no'], $stream);
           $flyAvg = $total / $number_of_sub; 
           $records[] = number_format($flyAvg,2).' '.$row['reg_no'];
        }
    }
    return $records;
}
    
$averages = Getter($stream);
foreach ($averages as $avg){
    echo $avg           
}
```

Please, I want to sort the output based on the avg with the students reg_no appended to it

| Output |
| --- |
| 54.20 FMS34 |
| 91.00 FMS51 |
| 72.16 FMS64 |
| 44.81 FMS23 |
| 68.52 FMS30 |
| 48.65 FMS37 |

My desired output is

| Output |
| --- |
| 91.00 FMS51 |
| 72.16 FMS64 |
| 68.52 FMS30 |
| 54.20 FMS34 |
| 48.65 FMS37 |
| 44.81 FMS23 |

Comment: Proper indentation would make this code a lot more readable. Have you tried to apply any [sorting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to your array?

Comment: there is always [a way](https://3v4l.org/VcCYl) - have a look at different options for [sorting arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: @brombeer Yes, I've tried using sort, but it's not working because of the appended reg_no which makes the value an associative array.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why a basic sort cannot do this. The fact that the `reg_no` is appended doesn't make it an associative array, it's still just an array of strings. It's just that each string has two values in it, and you want to sort in descending order of the value of the first part. Perhaps `usort()` is the way to do it, especially if the average may contain values that need to be sorted numerically.

Answer (score 0):

If your leading numbers are always two digits, then a decimal point, the two digits, then `rsort($records);` would suffice.

If they might be anything else, then keep a separate sorting array, then use `array_multisort()` to modify the `$records`.

```
public function Getter($stream): array
{
    $sql = "SELECT reg_no
            FROM hs_registration
            JOIN hs_students USING(reg_no)
            WHERE class_id = 2";
    $flyAvgs = [];
    $records = [];
    $number_of_sub = getNoSub();
    foreach ($database->query($sql) as $row) {
        $total = $this->totalScoreSpreadSheet($row['reg_no'], $stream);
        $flyAvg = $total / $number_of_sub;
        $flyAvgs[] = $flyAvg;
        $records[] = number_format($flyAvg, 2) . ' ' . $row['reg_no'];
    }
    array_multisort($flyAvgs, SORT_DESC, $records);
    return $records;
}
```